# How to separate column using an SSIS expression?

Tags: ssis

I have a CSV file and one of the columns is concatenated like: ".col1:.col2"

I am using SSIS to load CSV file into a SQL table.

How can I separate the column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

1. Add a data flow task
2. As data source set up a flat file connection, pointing to you CSV file.
3. Add a derive column transform, with two columns as follows:

Col1, with the expression: `SUBSTRING(COLNAME, 1, FINDSTRING(COLNAME, ":", 1) - 1)`

Col2, with the expression: `SUBSTRING(COLNAME, FINDSTRING(COLNAME, ":", 1) + 1, LEN(COLNAME) - FINDSTRING(COLNAME, ":", 1))`

Finally, load the relevant fields of the dataflow into you Sql destination.

I haven't tested the expressions myself, so they might have some one-off errors.